# Composer needs lib-openssl * while installling a repository

Tags: php, macos

I've been trying to get with "`Composer require jublonet/codebird-php`" and I get this error message

> jublonet/codebird-php 3.1.0 requires lib-openssl * -> the requested
>   linked library openssl has the wrong version installed or is missing
>   from your system, make sure to have the extension providing it.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this in the end?

Comment: Yes, at the end i found a piece of code that i have to write on terminal every time i reboot my laptop.